# Wrapping a float between a number system without IF statements in c++?

Tags: math, range

To wrap a number within a number system, you associate an index with a repeating set where the 0th index is always 0. eg, an index set table would be as follows for the range 0 thru 4

```
 INDEX: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
 RESULT:0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3
```

you can see this is similar to a modulus, until you do negative numbers, for example, a range -3 to 3, the relationship would look like

```
INDEX | RESULT
    -9|-2
    -8|-1
    -7|0
    -6|1
    -5|2
    -4|3
    -3|-3
    -2|-2
    -1|-1
     0|0
     1|1
     2|2
     3|3
     4|-3
     5|-2
     6|-1
```

and so on, and so fourth.

This can be applied to a set of decimals as well.
I want to write a function that can wrap a float for a range, but to optimize it, I don't want to use IF statements or loops. I'd like to have a mathematical solutions, so that processing this is straightforward, and quick, without interrupting the processor train.

How would one implement a system such as so?

any guidance on this would be awesome!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Thanks. I've been here before, but tend to delete my accounts due to the bad reception of questions

Comment: Just ask valid questions.

Comment: I do, but they're usually esoteric or,  so simple they get downvoted

Comment: Well, I linked you to the relevant material to read.

Comment: My question fits well with the help center,  no? It asks about a specific algorithm with very strict inputs, outputs, source.  The only thing I'm missing is some source,  which i attempt to replace with tables of data.

Comment: If you don't have (even examplary) c++ code, don't use the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: But then how are people supposed to know what  i mean by no ifs or loops?  For all i know,  they may give a solution in a stack based language,  which won't translate well to c++

Comment: @raymondchen i saw that but i don't think that's a valid solution that handles  negatives.... i may be wrong

Comment: Show examples for ranges `-5..-2, -3..1, 2..5`

Comment: It works for negatives because `floor` rounds toward negative infinity Even the OP asks about the negatives case. There is also a performance comparison that shows the `if` version is faster, so just use the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let assume we got wrap open range `(a0,a1)` where `a0<0` and `a1>0` and input number is `x` I would start experimenting with

```
x' = ((x/a0) - floor(x/a0))*a0 // negative x
x' = ((x/a1) - floor(x/a1))*a1 // positive x
```

Now the only problem how to decide which one to use without branching (`if` statements). I would use binary bit manipulation integer representation of `float` value. The sign bit is the **MSB** and `float` is 32 bit. So first obtain sign value of float and then convert it to `0` or `1`:

```cpp
unsigned int *px=(unsigned int*)&x;
float a=(unsigned int)(px[0]>>31);
```

Beware that `unsigned int` must be the same bit-width or less (but then use correct bit-shift of coarse) than `float` I usually use `DWORD` for such thing but not all compilers know such a type (it should be defined also in `windows.h` btw). Now just use it to select between the two equations. When I put all together in **C++**:

```cpp
float wrap(float x,float a0,float a1)
    {
    float a;
    a=x/a0; a0*=(a-floor(a));   // x<=0
    a=x/a1; a1*=(a-floor(a));   // x>=0
    unsigned int *px=(unsigned int*)&x; // px is integer representaion of x
    a=(unsigned int)(px[0]>>31);    // a = 0 for x>=0 and a = 1 for x<=0
    // now just combine
    a0*=(    a);
    a1*=(1.0-a);
    return a0+a1;
    }
```

Here result for range `(-3,+3)`

```
   x   |    x'
---------------
 -6.25 |  -0.25
 -6.00 |   0.00
 -5.75 |  -2.75
 -5.50 |  -2.50
 -5.25 |  -2.25
 -5.00 |  -2.00
 -4.75 |  -1.75
 -4.50 |  -1.50
 -4.25 |  -1.25
 -4.00 |  -1.00
 -3.75 |  -0.75
 -3.50 |  -0.50
 -3.25 |  -0.25
 -3.00 |   0.00
 -2.75 |  -2.75
 -2.50 |  -2.50
 -2.25 |  -2.25
 -2.00 |  -2.00
 -1.75 |  -1.75
 -1.50 |  -1.50
 -1.25 |  -1.25
 -1.00 |  -1.00
 -0.75 |  -0.75
 -0.50 |  -0.50
 -0.25 |  -0.25
---------------
  0.00 |   0.00
---------------
  0.25 |   0.25
  0.50 |   0.50
  0.75 |   0.75
  1.00 |   1.00
  1.25 |   1.25
  1.50 |   1.50
  1.75 |   1.75
  2.00 |   2.00
  2.25 |   2.25
  2.50 |   2.50
  2.75 |   2.75
  3.00 |   0.00
  3.25 |   0.25
  3.50 |   0.50
  3.75 |   0.75
  4.00 |   1.00
  4.25 |   1.25
  4.50 |   1.50
  4.75 |   1.75
  5.00 |   2.00
  5.25 |   2.25
  5.50 |   2.50
  5.75 |   2.75
  6.00 |   0.00
  6.25 |   0.25
```